# Applications of cut locus structure theorems

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I am preparing a presentation discussing the structure of the cut locus on Riemannian and Finsler manifolds. Since my audience will consist mostly of applied mathematicians, I was hoping to include some nice applications to other (non-geometric) areas of mathematics which might appeal to the majority of the audience. While I'm vaguely aware that there are some applications to regularity theory, I do not understand these results. I am therefore looking for a nice introduction to this topic in addition to any other applications which might appeal to a group of applied mathematicians.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cut locus of a point on a compact manifold has zero measure. So this allows to use a single chart centered at the point e.g. to compute integrals (typically radial coordinates in a chart given by the exponential).

You can exemplify this with the sphere (easy, the cut locus is a single point) and tori. The tori are related to Fourier analysis, so this hopefully speaks to applied mathematicians. Then show that there are more than just "square" tori. The cut locus depend on the lattice and since this is a Riemannian invariant, you can show that different tori are not isometric, and explain why we talk about the hexagonal lattice for the lattice built on $1$ and $e^{i {\pi \over 3}}$ (hint: the cut locus is a regular hexagon).

Concerning tori, you can then go slightly further along the relationship between Riemannian geometry and harmonic analysis, the link between isometry and isospectrality, and end up with the famous
"Can we hear the shape of a drum" talk and the 16-dimensional Milnor counterexample of two isospectral but not isometric tori, if you have time.

Comment: Hi coudy, thanks for your answer - I'm intrigued by the potential link to harmonic analysis (+1)! However, I'm skeptical about how exhibiting two isometrically distinct tori would appeal to applied mathematicians unless I could show they are isospectral. Could you perhaps spell this out a little more or provide a link to the basic theory which could help me figure this out? It would appear to me (https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~pberard/D/isos-dea93.pdf) that the tori are isospectral only if the squared lengths of the vertices on the dual lattices are the same, but I may have misunderstood

Comment: Milnor's article is actually one page long. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC300113/pdf/pnas00178-0006.pdf I also like the explicit constructions of non-isometric isospectral surfaces in the book of P. Buser, "Geometry and spectra of compact Riemann surfaces" ch12 . This is quite visual, just by gluing pair of pants. Finally I just noticed that the drum problem has its own wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_the_shape_of_a_drum. This may be a starting point.

Answer (score 13):

This does not fit your non-geometric requirement, but 
nevertheless "might appeal to a group of applied mathematicians":

> If you cut the cut locus of a point $x$ on the surface
>   of a convex polyhedron $P$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$,
>   then $P$ unfolds to the plane without self-overlap.

---

[image: CutLocus]


<sup>*Left*: The cut locus (red) w.r.t. $x$ on a box.
*Right*: Unfolding resulting from cutting the cut locus.


(Figure from [Discrete and Computational Geometry](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9489.html).)</sup>

---

This result generalizes to $\mathbb{R}^d$ for $d > 3$, unfolding
without overlap to dimension $d-1$.

Comment: Ooh, I'll be borrowing this if I ever teach a geometry class. It is a neat way to unfurl definitions that should help students with understanding what is going on!

Comment: Hi Joseph, this is a really nice geometric application! However, as you say yourself, I am looking for something a little more in the area of (ostensibly) non-geometric topics such as the likes of PDE theory or analysis, of interest to a broad class of applied mathematicians. As such I might leave the question open for a little bit to see what other people may think about this.

Comment: Just one word: wow!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possibility:

> Villani, Cédric. "Regularity of optimal transport and cut locus: From nonsmooth analysis to geometry to smooth analysis." *Discrete Contin. Dyn. Sys.* 30.2 (2011): 559-571.

**Abstract**. In this survey paper I describe the convoluted links between the regularity theory of optimal transport and the geometry of cut locus.

> **Theorem 4.1** (convex Earth). [...]
>   Informally speaking: assume that the Earth is very smooth, but not
>   exactly round (there are hills etc.) The theorem says that if you draw a map of the Earth from one given point, it may not look round, but at least it will look convex"